# DocuSign API.NET + it skip SMS authentication page when accessing the signing page from email notification

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We are using SMS authentication for signing of envelope via DocuSign API. During the testing, we notice that when we access the signing page from DocuSign email, it will skip the SMS authentication page and go to the signing page directly. However if we access directly from DocuSign web, it will redirect us to the SMS authentication page before signing. So I am unsure if we have missed out any configuration setting/code. We are using DEV account (have checked with the support that SMS authentication is already enabled for this account).

Please find the following for more information.
[DocuSign Account Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am4c7.png)
[Code for SMS authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SEnI.png)